# How do I convert contours into chain code?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to turn the edges of my image into chain code.

***code***

```
edges = cv2.Canny(resized,100,200, L2gradient=True) 
contour = str(cv2.findContours(edges, mode = "CV_RETR_LIST", method = "CV_CHAIN_CODE" ))
print(contour)
```

***output***

```
contour = str(cv2.findContours(edges, mode = "CV_RETR_LIST", method = "CV_CHAIN_CODE" ))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I've tried replacing the strings with numbers but I'm not sure which numbers correspond with the method and mode.

Comment: 1) As the error message indicates, `mode` and `method` require integers, but you provide strings like `"CV_RETR_LIST"`. The proper calling is `mode=cv2.CV_RETR_LIST` (maybe without cv2 depending on the version), which is an enumeration value, which is basically just an integer, cf. [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) 2) Which version of OpenCV do you use? [It seems, CV_CHAIN_CODE has been removed some time ago.](https://answers.opencv.org/question/136689/freeman-chain-code-in-opencv-3/)

Comment: Do you still need help in this question ?

Comment: @0xPrateek, yes I would still like to be able to find a way to turn my edge array into chain code, but it seems that this is no longer a feature in opencv2.